# How to set the URL for "Login to Community as User" button

Tags: community, user, button, login

When I click on the "Login to Community as User" button, it takes me to this odd URL that doesn't exist any longer. I'm assuming it was configured to be so by a previous admin.

Where do I find the setting to change the URL to pop-open the current community home instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338769&type=1&mode=1 might help

Comment: Login to Community as User is typically a standard button that you can't configure.  If your previous admin configured a custom button with the same name, you should check the Button section on the Contact object in Setup.